# Continuous maps direct limit topology

Tags: general-topology

We consider a direct limit of a tower $X_1\subset\cdots\subset X_n$ of spaces, where each $X_n$ is a subspace of $X_{n+1}$. The direct limit is $X_\infty:=\bigcup_n X_n$ endowed with the topology $\mathcal{T}_\infty$ defined as follows: $U\subset X_\infty$ is open if and only if $\forall n\in \Bbb{N},\quad U\cap X_n$ is open on $\mathcal{T_n}.$

We assume that $\mathcal{T}_n$ is the subspace topology on $X_n$ by $\mathcal{T}_{n+1}.$

Now given a topological space $Y$ if we have a continuous map $\phi_n:X_n\to Y$ such that for all $n,\quad \phi_n=\phi_{n+1}\restriction X_n.$

Then if $\phi_\infty$ is the function that coincide with $\phi_n$ in restriction to $X_n,$ does $\phi_\infty$ is continuous ? Unique ?

For continuous I would say that if $U$ is an open set of $Y$ then $\phi_\infty^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal{T}_\infty$ because $\phi_\infty^{-1}(U)\cap X_n=\phi_n^{-1}(U)$ right ?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. The construction is quite general, and called the [final topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology). Instead of inclusions necessarily, we have a family $f_{\lambda}:X_{\lambda} \to Y$ of functions where each $X_{\lambda}$ has a topology and $Y$ is just a set. Then, the final topology (which is the largest topology on $Y$ making all $f_{\lambda}$ continuous, and you can readily spell out what the faces of the open sets will be) satisfies the property that given any topological space $Z$, $g:Y \to Z$ is continuous if and only if each $g \circ f_{\lambda}$ is.